# OpenVPN GUI client for UDP/TCP

Tags: software-recommendation, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

Is there any easy solution for OpenVPN being executed from Desktop for non technician people so they only push a button and get connected to a external VPN? 
Most of my colleagues are non Linux proficients. So, their interaction with CL is very limited.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I know this is not the GUI method but openvpn couldn't be any more simple or elementary as far as the commandline goes and really does not need a GUI. The command to start an openvpn session is as follows:

```
sudo openvpn --config
```

and then drag and drop the ".ovpn" file into the terminal to complete the command so it should look something like this example:

```
sudo openvpn --config '/home/jglerner/Desktop/vpnbook-us1-tcp443.ovpn'
```

press enter, enter your password for sudo, enter your vpn username, then your vpn password and you're good to go.

Users can minimize the open terminal if they don't want to look at it while it's running. Plus, it might give your "non linux pals" a bit of commandline confidence when they see how easy something like this can be.

Example .ovpn file used in this example can be downloaded from here http://www.vpnbook.com/ if you want to check it out and see how it works. Just download the certificate bundle and extract the zip file. There are two TCP and two UDP servers to choose from. The username is "freevpnme" and the password is listed on the download page, however, the password changes day to day to prevent abuse and spam but the cert. files stay the same.

Comment: Thanks, I´ll give it a try. My VPN provider provides a XXX.ovpn file. I have already installed it under a rooter (dd-wrt messed and stuff :-) )so, I think, it will do the trick. Not as difficult as I may see. I´ll keep you informed. Now I´ll need to clean some *.conf files I have already started to garble.

Comment: Just for starters I tried OPenVPN on my Windows box and it works. I think that your solution will work as well in Linux.I´ll try it tomorrow morning. \o/

Comment: if you have a vpn provider with more than 500 servers, good luck for adding all of them

Comment: @Mehdi Good luck using more than one vpn at a time, let alone 500; your connection would be soooo slow. However, it shouldn't be too hard to batch download all 500 ovpn files to a single directory where the user can select which one to use each time. No luck needed :) Just drag and drop the file into the terminal; it's super easy.

Comment: I was talking about adding all 500 servers manually to the network manager to be able to switch from one to another at any time. There is more than drag and drop there as you need three files for each server (Nordvpn) plus writing your username and password. But I found a script to make this automatic https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2016/05/05/how-to-automatically-import-nordvpn-servers/

Comment: @Mehdi I don't know, the instructions here: https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/linux/openvpn/ pretty much follow my same instructions. It looks like you only need one file, the ovpn file to drag and drop or just the name of the file is sufficient if you feel like typing and have downloaded to the same directory or you could include the full path if you feel like typing all of that as well. If you do need three, it looks like those are all included in the same zip file and only need to be in the same directory so cd to that directory probably if that is the case.

Comment: @Mehdi I see there is a need to download the cert files. This is specific and would nedd to be addressed in a separate question although, other than downloading and unzipping the cert files, it remains the same simple command along with the ovpn file of the chosen server and then press enter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works well. However, is there a way to automate it? I have two servers to which I want to connect and I don't want to enter username and password each time for each server.

Comment: @SlavaFominII If you open this as a question, I will certainly provide an answer for you. Please leave me a reply here to let me know so that I will receive a notification

Answer (score 34):

Here's how I did this in ubuntu 16.04.

I used Network Manager -- access this via right-click on the little "networking icon" in the system tray, e.g.:

[image]

I already had Network Manager, but I needed to install OpenVPN and two extensions for Network Manager:

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn  
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn  
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

Even if you're not running Gnome, you can install the Gnome extension for OpenVPN -- it will run just fine inside Unity, for example, and it's needed for the following setup:

**Right-click Network Manager** in the **System Tray**, select **Edit**:

[image: edit connection]

click **Add**:

[image: add new connection]

In the dropdown, select to import the vpn config:

[image: import saved vpn config]

Select the `.ovpn` config file from your file system:

[image: choose vpn config]

Once this is setup, **right-click** on **Network Manager > VPN Connections** and select the connection to connect.  To disconnect, do the same:

[image: connect to vpn]

Comment: This worked beautifully - for me the closest thing to OpenVPN GUI on Windows or TunnelBlick on Mac, which is what I was after.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer !

Comment: This is by far the best solution

Comment: Unable to import open.config for 2.8.4 version using this methodology

Comment: With openvpn versions on ubuntu 20.04 have huge bug. This client ignores the directvive pull-filter ignore redirect-gateway.

Comment: Works perferctly on Ubuntu 22.04.2. I don't know why I missed this before. I've been using the command line for years!

Answer (score 21):

Adding an OpenVPN connection via the Network preferences with `network-manager-openvpn-gnome` installed, defaults to using UDP instead of TCP. If you want to connect via TCP, it is under the *Advanced* settings you can get to by clicking that button on the *VPN* tab of the configuration GUI.

Comment: Open the .ovpn file and you'll find some hints on what to set for the vpn. Hover over each setting and you'll see what config line to check. For example where it says `config: ca` choose the `ca.crt` file if the ovpn file has the line `ca ca.crt`. If the ovpn file has `cipher AES-256-CBC` choose it under the cipher tab of Advanced - Security where the tooltip says `config:cipher`. If you have `dev tap` in file check the "Use a Tap device", etc.

Answer (score 7):

You can install the `network-manager-openvpn-gnome` package to enable OpenVpn GUI in Ubuntu or other linuxes that have `network-manager`:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try free and open source Pritunl client

https://client.pritunl.com/

To install it on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pritunl.list << EOF
deb http://repo.pritunl.com/stable/apt xenial main
EOF

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7568D9BB55FF9E5287D586017AE645C0CF8E292A
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pritunl-client-electron
```

[image]

Comment: wow! an electron-based VPN client! :D (mind-blown)

Answer (score 2):

**Easiest way (Desktop environment GUI) :**

As **Hawkeye Parker** told, You can simply use this built-in option for it by following this:

1. **setting -> network -> VPN**
2. click on **+** and select **import from file...** [Add VPN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Uqbv.png)
3. now select `.ovpn` file [Select .opvn file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2xiY.png)
4. configure it (username/ password) [VPN configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyb2f.png)

Feel free to change **name** field to whatever you want.

I tried it on **20.04 LTS** version

Comment: Hello. This may be an answer but what about later when all the links are no longer valid?

Comment: hey @David, it can not happen, links are images, and images are hosted by askubuntu servers just like other images. As a New contributor, I could not post images until I made some reputation

Comment: You are mistaken.  Imgur keep images for ever as long as they are receiving at least 1 view every six months. If they are not they may be deleted to save space.

Comment: @David, I didn't know. I will change the links as soon as I can. Thank you for saying that :)

Comment: @daway0 How to configure Google (OAuth) based authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a .desktop file and insert the terminal string or call a bash script after the "exec" in the file

Comment: This is not managebale (how to check status of connection, disconnect and etc..)!