# Running OpenVPN client version

Tags: server, vpn, openvpn, client, syslinux

I install OpenVPN version 2.5.5.

But I can't run its client version.

[image]

*I am using Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Which error are you getting? The screenshot shows version info, but no errors.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Just copy the text here and use code formatting https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN does not include a graphical user interface. You may want to install Network Manager for this purpose. Another user answered how to do that [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/977172/1052446).