# I need a secure method to access the internet over a hotel's open wi-fi (TOR proxy?)

Tags: networking, wireless, iptables, proxy, tor

I need to communicate securely over a hotels open wi-fi. I've read many articles and how-to's.
Using a TOR server/proxy sounds good. I can't access my bank, my email, etc. through the clear-text
nature of open wi-fi. I'm thinking of a TOR client on my laptop and using eth0 to a Raspberry Pi 3B+
running a TOR server with the appropriate IPtable setup, etc., to forward my requests to the hotels
open wi-fi.

I've read so many how-to's, I would like recommendations to links that are not full of "gotcha's".
I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.05 on my laptop and the latest RasPi OS. All recommendations would be
appreciated.

HH

Comment: "I would like recommendations to links "  we do not do "links"  ;-) Oh and Opera has a built in VPN. So does Brave browser.

Comment: I strongly recommend not to access your bank, emails or any other account that is important through TOR. Just pay for a good VPN service, it's worth it. If you really want to access those types of personal accounts while on a hotel and not pay for a VPN, you can create a hotspot with your mobile phone and connect to it, make sure it has a strong password. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by securely. Tor is likely not secure for many things like banking or anything involving your actual identity or personal information. A VPN will be secure more like your home network if that's what you're looking for. However, if you just want to look at some sketchy stuff or surf the net with anonymity, then TOR is probably your best bet. Again, it depends on the context.

Comment: Openvpn is super easy to use on Ubuntu. See [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/508296/167115) on how to use the .ovpn file downloaded from your VPN provider. However, you will need to install openvpn from the Ubuntu software center first.